# use Request's rules to refuse a specific value

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-5.3

i m new with laravel 5.3. i have a form and i want to show an error if a user tape a specifique caracter

**for exemple if user tape 0 and click on submit, an error will be shown**

I m trying to do it by setting **rules** for **my Request** for exemple :

```
    class calcRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'num1'=>'required',
            'num2'=>'required',
            'op'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

num2 should be diffrent from 0

How could i do it ? thnks

Comment: You can use `not_in:` . You can see the example at there : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-not-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not_in:0` . You can follow the example at [there](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-not-in)

```
'num2' => 'required|not_in:0',
```

Comment: Thnk so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `num2` is an integer. In this case you can use [`min`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-min) rule:

```
'num2' => 'required|integer|min:1',
```